Text in reflection
I'm new here in this blender world and I really need your help with a college project. I'm sorry if anything is written wrong as I'm using Google Translate. I am from Brazil
How to create a script in which I write the text I want and it creates an irregular surface that, when the light hits it at a certain angle, reflects the same text as the video.
How can I create something like this in Blender to simulate a real situation?
Video link



Hello, are you using Eevee or Cycles? In Cycles you can assign an image texture to a spot light. In Eevee I guess you'll need to cheat

In fact, I don't even know where to start, that's why I'm asking for your help.
The idea is to transform the text into a texture like in the video and photo and when reflecting the light it will show the text.

To simulate this in a physically accurate manner you would need to look into reflection Caustics, unfortunately Cycles doesn't excel at that, I'm not entirely sure it is actually even possible. You can fake it with a textured lamp https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57013/correct-vector-input-to-map-texture-light-in-cycles

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154876/how-to-fake-reflective-caustics-in-cycles

Yup.. no way would surface normals / Cycles caustics be able to simulate this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2yV6IeL-Jw It would need a fake, IMO.

Thanks guys, all help is welcome. I see that this is really very difficult to do. The simulation in Blender has to be as close to a real situation as possible. Because the next step was to create the piece in some way.
